# Do not require phone number on paypal form, adaptive payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using parallel payments API. Both my test accounts in sandbox have it set to not require a customers phone number, but when I test checkout it's still required.

Is it possible to not require it through app settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to suppress this on the payment page.  The reason for this is that, even though you don't require the customer's phone number, PayPal still requires it.  This is so that PayPal can contact a customer if there's an issue with their transaction, so that PayPal can identify them when they call into customer service, etc.